# jqGrid: grid function executes only once

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Sorry, this is a Javascript beginner question. My jqGrid function works fine the first time around, but when I call it a second time, nothing happens, no request is issued. Code fragment:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var brandsDropdown = document.getElementById("brandsDropdown");
    var brandId = brandsDropdown.options[brandsDropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    var searchParams = "brandId=" + brandId;
    doGrid(searchParams);
  });
});

function doGrid(searchParams) {
alert("doGrid, searchParams:" + searchParams);
var url="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/services/setup/project";
var editurl="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/services/setup/project";
$("#projectList").jqGrid({
    url: url + "?" + searchParams,
    editurl: editurl,
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'GET',
    ...
});
```

The alert() shows me that doGrid() is really called successfully the second time. So it's really the $("projectList").jqGrid() function that doesn't execute, or fails silently .. Unless I made an obvious mistake in the way I call it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the second time is no longer a need to regenerate the entire Grid. Then you only change the set parameters and grid computing to date. For this you need a `trigger("reloadGrid")` call.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

> var runonce=false;

```
  $("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var brandsDropdown = document.getElementById("brandsDropdown");
    var brandId = brandsDropdown.options[brandsDropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    var searchParams = "brandId=" + brandId;
    doGrid(searchParams);
  });
});

function doGrid(searchParams) {
    alert("doGrid, searchParams:" + searchParams);
    var url="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/services/setup/project";
    var editurl="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/services/setup/project";

     if (false==runonce) {

        $("#projectList").jqGrid({
            url: url + "?" + searchParams,
            editurl: editurl,
            datatype: 'xml',
            mtype: 'GET',
            ...
        });
        runonce=true;
     } else {
         $("#projectList").jqGrid({
             url: url + "?" + searchParams,
             editurl: editurl
         }).trigger("reloadGrid");

     }
```